# How to get keys from hash ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key

The next code search if keyword appear in hash values and print yes if so,
but it works well in codeacademy console, but in my Rubymine it give me exception

NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

I've tried to use each_key method but it was the same rusult.

```
arr = [
 { name: "2222", num:"4444 kod"},
 { name: "3222 kod", num:"43423444"},
 { name: "224422", num:"4442424"}
]

p = "kod"

arr.each do |frelancer|
frelancer.keys.each do |key|
    if frelancer[key].split(" ").include? (p)
        puts "yes"
    esle 
  puts "no"
    end
```

end

Can you give some advice?)

Comment: Post the real code - clearly this doesn't parse (e.g. `esle`)

Comment: Where is `end` for two blocks you wrote? Ruby =/= Python

Comment: When the syntax issues in your code are fixed, it runs fine for me and produces: `no, yes, yes, no, no, no`. What's the problem?

Comment: As @Alex said, correct the spelling of `esle` and add one more `end` at the end and your code will run correctly.  Note that you would have noticed the missing `end` if you had formatted your code properly.  Also, to make your output more meaningful, consider adding a statement such as the following after `frelancer.keys.each do |key|`: `print "frelancer[#{key}] = '#{frelancer[key]}' contains '#{p}': "`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 mistakes:

1. You wrote `esle` instead of `else`
2. You are missing one `end` clause

Answer (score 0):

Your blocks need `end` keyword. And `else` should be spelt correctly.

```rb
arr.each do |frelancer|
  frelancer.keys.each do |key|
    if frelancer[key].split(" ").include? (p)
      puts "yes"
    else  
      puts "no"
    end  
  end  
end
```